# Flash AS3.0 Error 1119

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I have the following error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'smashNow', Frame 138, Line 1   1119: Access of possibly undefined property `onRelease` through a reference with static type `flash.display:SimpleButton`.

Here is my code:

```
play_mc.onRelease= function ()
{
    GotoAndPlay ("Scene 3",1)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not **AS3** at all! Try something like this:

```
play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 3");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Actionscript 2 instead of Actionscript 3. Also, you might think about renaming play_mc to something like play_button, since it's not a movieclip, it's a button (SimpleButton).

The clean way to do it is like this:

```
play_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMyScene, false, 0, true);

function playMyScene(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 3");
}
```